# Is there a name for this general problem (variation on least squares)?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-optimization

The problem statement is as follows.

> Minimize $||g(X\beta)-y||^2$ with respect to $\beta$ where $g(\cdot)$ is some non-linear function, $y$ and $\beta$ are column vectors.

General *linear* least squares problems are of form $\text{argmin}_\beta\{||X\beta-y||^2\}$ and have plenty of solutions. Simply calling the above problem *non-linear* least squares produces a myriad of search results and none suits my need. Is there a name for this? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers! = )

Comment: Well, it *is* a nonlinear least squares problem, in which case there are a number of excellent algorithms (Gauss-Newton, Levenberg-Marquardt, etc.) for finding solutions numerically. See [this](http://www.netlib.org/toms/573) as well.

Comment: Thank you, the link is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try any numerical analysis book on multidimensional minimization.  I don't think the fact that $\beta$ is a vector as opposed to a set of parameters will help.  Section 10.4 and on of [Numerical Recipes](http://nr.com/) is one source and the obsolete ones are free.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a great book. Don't know why I've never heard of it.